# How to pass data from child template to parent template then to included template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, template-inheritance, template-context

Basically what i want to accomplish is be able to access some variable or content from a template after performing `extend` then `include`.

No better way to explain what i want to do better than a sample code so,

- **home.html**

  ```
  {% with page="homepage" %}
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
  ```
- **base.html**

  ```
  {% include "sidebar.html" with origin=page %}
  ```
- **sidebar.html**

  ```
  <h1>This is {{ origin }}'s sidebar</h1>
  ```

In the above example i want to end up with a header stating "**This is homepage's sidebar**"

Is there any built-in way to do so in Django? if not is there any non built-in solution?

**Edit**

I know it may seem that what i am trying to do can be accomplished by passing the data from within the view as template context. however that is not what i am trying to do, i want to set the variable or the content from within the template itself.